# React Multi-page Recipe App Design - Generate and Save HTML Pages Dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am building a **recipe app** in react for practice. The idea is that once a recipe thumbnail on the main page is clicked, it takes you to a new html devoted to the selected recipe. I want it to have the ability to **add new recipes** in the future so it should be dynamic.

So I would like to **store recipe data in a database** and **generate a recipe subpage using react**, after the relevant thumbnail is clicked (eventually I want subpages to be interactive, too). But I struggle to find **examples or info about that type of architecture on the internet**. Is it at all done? Is there an alternative way to handle such things?

Perhaps I should **give up the idea** that every recipe should have a **dedicated html page** (which just seemed intuitive), and just let the recipe **be a component** all within the main html?

*For the record: as this is practice in javascript, all the 'database' info is saved as js files, which I know is not realistic, but I'm fine with it.*

Answer (score 0):

React Router is what you are looking for: https://reactrouter.com/web/guides/quick-start
When installed, you can define routes like this:

```
<Route exact path='/recipes' component={ListComponent} />
<Route exact path='/recipe/:id' component={DetailComponent} />
```

So the recipe with the ID 1 will be at /recipe/1